# Magento password field is blank in new account create email

Tags: php, email, magento

In Magento Enterprise ver. 1.14.1.0, When I create new account there is password field is blank in email, we have tried change to template  go to `app->locale->en_GB->template->email`  and change file  account_email.html

```
   <strong>Email</strong>: {{var customer.email}}<br/>   (Working Fine)
   <strong>Password</strong>: {{htmlescape var=$customer.password}}(Blank field place of password)
```

**htmlescape var=$customer.password**    this line gives blank in new mail.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check release notes for latest Magento versions:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes#ce19-1910

- Customer passwords are no longer stored in clear text during registration.

Magento cannot send password in mails, because does not have it.

I think password link is left in template for backwards compatibility. I suggest you to delete this string from template.

Comment: Hi,thanks for reply  ,actually we have another project on 1.9.0.1,there is nothing problem,we can see email and password both.

Comment: This changes was made in 1.9.1.0

Comment: You are right,actually that was the problem,finally fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are right,the functionality has been removed from 1.9.1.0.  ,while I was testing on 1.9.0.1,

**Remember**  - functionality is exiting in 1.9.0.1   while it has been removed from 1.9.1.0.
Please check link
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes#ce19-1910

Thanks